# How to assign Datagrid DataSource to Model with ASP.NET MVC FrameWork

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, datagrid

Using ASP.NET MVC I am able to access Model as below:

```
 <% foreach (var item in Model) { %>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <%: Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CompanyName) %>
            </td>         
        </tr>
    <% } %>
```

So Can I assign datagrid data source similarly. Let's say:

```
 <asp:DataGrid ID="dataGrid1" runat="server" DataSource="<% Model %>"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you wrongly understood ASP.Net MVC.

```
 ASP.Net MVC does not support server side controls.
```

It is supported only in web-forms , the programming model is completely different when compared to asp.net web-forms.

All the **server side** controls depends/uses **viewstate**, which is not supported by asp.net mvc.

If you want to achieve, grid functionality , you can go for asp.net **mvc webgrid** or you can also choose between using java script open source libraries such as

```
Jqgrid , jquery Data tables etc.
```

**Before, you start working with ASP.net mvc** ,

```
i strongly recommend you to understand difference between webforms  and mvc , which controls are suppported etc.
```

Hope this helps..

**Note: You can not use asp.net server controls in ASP.Net MVC**

***Updated:***

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/668182/Difference-betweeen-ASP-NET-WebForms-and-ASP-NET-M

Here, is the link that gives you the differences between webforms and mvc

Comment: Just the pefect guidelines , Love the differences